# Installing Flume, Kafka, Hive, Hbase and Zookeeper on Hadoop multi node in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-kafka, flume

I have installed Hadoop in multi node configuration and wants to install Flume, Kafka, Hive, Hbase and Zookeeper also.

Do I need to install all the components on only master nodes or on all the nodes?

Comment: Define "master" node. HBase's master can be different than say, the namenode in HDFS.

Comment: master node means hadoop master node that has primary namenode.

Comment: Well, like I said, there are different "master" nodes per Hadoop tool. I feel like the only ones that you listed that should be on all the nodes are Zookeeper, Flume, and Kafka. The rest can be distributed amongst the namenode and other nodes. Just be sure to accommodate for resource constraints. If you are using Ambari or Cloudera Manager, installing these services would be fairly straightforward

Comment: Just to be sure whether I have understood it correctly or not.

Till now I have installed Hadoop on a fresh VM and created 4 nodes (Multi node configuration).
Namenode

Datanode1

Datanode2

Datanode3


Now you want me to install Kafka, Flume and offcourse Zookeeper on all the 4 nodes and the rest on only the Datanode?

Comment: The rest can either be on the datanode or a combination of datanodes and the namenode. It's really up to you and the resources available to your machines.